# Borde de boton en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen dia, tengo un boton con la propiedad de flatstyle puesta en flat, ahora lo que pasa es que cuando este boton es el control activo del formulario el borde cambia de tamaño, quisiera saber si hay una manera de evitar eso, estoy trabajando en visual studio 2012.
Tipo del proyecto: win-forms.

[image: El boton de minimizar es el activo y tiene un borde mas grueso]

Comment: Que tipo de proyecto tienes, win-forms, wpf, asp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementa a tu boton el `EventHandler` `GotFocus`

```
 this.myBoton.GotFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.myBoton_GotFocus);
```

Cuando tome el enfoque tu botón, deshabilitalo! mediante: `myBoton.Enabled = false;` :

```
private void myBoton_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myBoton.Enabled = false;
}
```

De esta forma nunca veras la sombra que se ve al enfocar el botón.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los dos tiene el mismo tamaño de borde pero al seleccionar cualquiera de los dos el borde de ese se hace mas grueso.

Comment: Ya veo cual es el borde, es al enfocar el botón, he actualizado mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: @josemarquez revisa esta [respuesta en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9400099/4092887)

Comment: Eso es lo que trató Jose anteriormente, aquí el problema se presenta cuando el botón esta enfocado, por lo tanto hay que deshabilitar el enfoque.

Answer (score 0):

Es un comportamiento de winform al obtener el foco el control, lo único que se me ocurre es que en el evento GotFocus del botón le cambies el foco a otro control.