# ¿Por qué aparece un borde en el botón seleccionado?

Tags: java, botón

Tengo una aplicación en java, con un `JFrame` y un `JPanel`, sobre los cuales tengo varios botones.

Los botones tienen la configuración que les adjunto en la imágen y código.

Cuando hago click en uno de los botones aparece el borde que se logra ver en la última imágen, pero en las configuraciones tengo especificado que no exista borde. Sólo se muestra ese borde en el seleccionado.

Todos los botones tienen un `pressedIcon` con la misma imagen pero con un tamaño más pequeño, después de ser presionados vuelve a la imagen original. No sé si esto ocasiona el problema.

Mi duda es ¿Por qué aparece ese borde y cómo puedo evitarlo?

Éste es el código que me genera automático NetBeans para los botones:

```
    btnLuz.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    btnLuz.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft YaHei", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    btnLuz.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    btnLuz.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\prueba\\Desktop\\img\\Light On-64.png")); // NOI18N
    btnLuz.setText("LUZ ON");
    btnLuz.setBorder(null);
    btnLuz.setBorderPainted(false);
    btnLuz.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    btnLuz.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    btnLuz.setHideActionText(true);
    btnLuz.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    btnLuz.setIconTextGap(-4);
    btnLuz.setPressedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\prueba\\Desktop\\img\\Light On-48.png")); // NOI18N
    btnLuz.setRolloverEnabled(false);
    btnLuz.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    btnLuz.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    jPanel1.add(btnLuz, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 50, 90, 80));
```

[image: Config. Boton]

[image: Boton-Borde]

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el borde es del botón? Podría ser de otro elemento. Sólo con las imágenes es difícil de saber. ¿Tienes el código?

Comment: Dentro de la clase donde esta el jframe no tengo codigo, todo lo manejo desde otro paquete.
Para cada boton uso un actionListener para inicializarlo y un action performed para usarlo.

Comment: v.btnLuz.addActionListener(this);  <---- Así inicio.
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        try {
            
           if(e.getActionCommand().equals("LUZ ON")){

                String mensaje = "1";

Y así lo uso. El programa funciona a la perfeccion, solo ese detalle me tiene loco.

Comment: La primera imagen que usas como ejemplo de cómo configuras el botón se transforma en código. Porque uses una herramienta para facilitartelo no significa que no lo haya. Todo al final es código que se compila.

Comment: Claro, lo entiendo, lo que quiero decir es que use la herramienta grafica para modificar la apariencia delos botones, la funcionalidad de los mismos es la que manejo desde otra clase en un paquete diferente :)

Comment: Por cierto, justo ese borde gris que aparece muestra el tamaño real del boton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad es un borde que aparece cuando el botón se enfoca, tienes que deshabilitar el enfoque mediante [setFocusable()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable(boolean)) :

```
button.setFocusable(false)
```

o mediante [setFocusPainted()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setFocusPainted(boolean)) :

```
button.setFocusPainted(false)
```

---

Me hizo recordar esta pregunta (en C#) donde el usuario deseaba eliminar el borde, en realidad se generaba cuando el botón obtenia el enfoque:

[Borde de boton en c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32772/borde-de-boton-en-c)

Comment: Lo pruebo y veo si sirve, muchas gracias!

Comment: Excelente @FabianVelazquezZuñiga me da gusto, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El borde que te aparece no es un borde es el foco al botón. Puedes deshabilitarlo poniendo en los botones la siguiente línea:

```
btnLuz.setFocusPainted(false);
```

Lo explica en otra [pregunta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361658/disable-jbutton-focus-border).

Comment: Lo pruebo y veo si sirve, muchas gracias!

Comment: @FabianVelazquezZuñiga de nada. Seguro que es eso por lo que me dijiste en los comentarios. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como buena para que otro pueda aprovecharlo.